# ¿Que tipo de datos uso para añadir una imagen a una clase en javafx?

Tags: javafx

[image]

¿Que tipo de datos uso para añadir una imagen en una clase javafx?, voy a subirla a mysql como BLOB.

Comment: Hola. Con un poco de google habrías obtenido tu respuesta: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, mi pregunta va más enfocada al tipo de datos para almacenar en la clase y la bbdd, por ejemplo, en java swing almacenaba la ruta en la bbdd y la imagen en una carpeta,  y lo trataba como tipo string. En java fx estoy buscando su hay otra opción diferente o mejor.

Comment: Ya lo dices en la pregunta: para la BD puedes usar BLOB https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html pero del lado de Java la clase es Image Es lo que preguntabas, según veo...

Comment: Vale te entiendo ahora, tienes razón, me refería más a sí hay algún tipo de "Property" para manipularlas en la clase ya sea Byte o Image como son StringProperty o IntegerProperty. No obstante según veo lo almacenado como Image directamente. Es más, seguramente lo haga a la ,"vieja usanza" y almacene la url y copie las imágenes a un directorio en vez de almacenar la imagen directamente. Cual usarias, basándome que es para una tienda.